# Writing a calculator by using a method int sum(String s)?

Tags: java

I just begun learning java and I don't know why my code doesn't work. This is the assignment:

Write a class named Calculator with a method int sum(String s). String s contains a set of integers separated by white space (blanks, tabs, or newlines). Return the sum of the integers.

You can use a Scanner object to solve this problem. Create a new Scanner(s) and store it in a variable, say in. Then, use in.hasNextInt() to control a while loop. Each iteration of the while loop uses in.nextInt() to get the next integer from the String s. Accumulate this integer into a variable and return that variable when the loop exits.

You may use a main method to test your method by creating an instance of the Calculator class and calling sum(…) with several combinations of values using that instance.

For example, sum(“3 4 5 27 3”) is 42.

And this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {
    int sum(String s) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(s);
        while (in.hasNextInt())  {        
            in.nextInt();     
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see yourself summing anything anywhere in that code?

Comment: your teacher gives the answer already. you just need to follow the instruction :)

Comment: All the algorithm is detailed in your assignment, you should have no problem to implement it.

Comment: Not seeing a variable to accumulate the sum. Not seeing that variable being returned. Not seeing a main() to test. not seeing a lot of effort...

Comment: Sum means adding things together. You have no addition anywhere in your code. `in.nextInt()` is grabbing an int, then throwing it away. The part of the instructions you missed is "_Accumulate this integer_ **into a variable** _and return that variable when the loop exits._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int sum(String s) {
    int i = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(s);
    while (in.hasNextInt())  {        
        i += in.nextInt();     
    }
    return i;
}
```

The assignment tells you to do the method. You can call the method from the main method with the appropriate string.

Comment: But try to use meaningful variable names like "sum" or "accumulator" instead of "i". If OP is new to java, its good to start learning with good habits.